# Confirming a message in REST - is it PUT or POST?

Tags: api, rest

One of our services generates messages and each message needs to be confirmed. However, the message itself is only identified via it's "type of message", not an ID.

What is the proper HTTP verb for acknowledging the message?

Is it PUT or POST?

Comment: I think (I may be wrong) PUT method are used for an entire update of a specific resource, and POST for (generally) creating something like an object, ... etc.
 In your context, I would do it with a PUT. 
Docs at the mozilla.org site are very clear and simple, I would recommend you to 
[check it out](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods) for the different http methods.

Answer (score 0):

If the message does not have a unique ID, then you cannot identify it, so how would you update its status or how do you find it in the database at all? At least generate an MD5 checksum from the JSON representation of the text and other properties `md5({message,senderID,receiverID,timestamp,...})`. to get an identifier you can use to find the message. After that you can make an endpoint something like `/messages/{md5-checksum}` and do `PUT /messages/{md5-checksum}/confirmed true`. You can do POST too `POST /messages/{md5-checksum}/confirmation -`, but I like PUT better in this scenario.